# How to write "There is at least 3" in logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I need to know how to write "There is at least 3 "in the logic language

For example : There is at least 3 cars in the garage

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To say that there exists (at least one) is $\exists x$ $P(x)$.

To say there exists  at least two is $\exists x ( P(x) \wedge \exists y (P(x) \wedge y \ne x ))$

Thus, to say there exists at least 3:

$$\exists x (P(x) \wedge \exists y (P(y) \wedge y \ne x \wedge (\exists z (P(z) \wedge z \ne y \wedge z \ne x))))$$

Comment: Is there a compact way of writing this for $n$ objects, like $\sum$ or $\prod$ or $\bigcup$ etc?

Comment: Using basic logic symbols? No. However, there are plenty of symbols invented and generally accepted to simplify this. I am not a logician so I am not qualified to answer as to exactly which symbol would work and also be generally accepted.

Answer (score 5):

If you wrote $\exists^{\ge 3}$ to mean "there exist at least three", you'd probably be understood.

If you wanted to be super pedantic you could define the symbol $\exists^{\ge n}$ for all $n \ge 1$ recursively, by defining
$$\exists^{\ge 1} x,\, P(x) \equiv \exists x,\, P(x)$$
$$\exists^{\ge n+1}x,\, P(x) \equiv \exists x,\, P(x) \wedge (\exists^{\ge n}y,\, (P(y) \wedge y \ne x))$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\exists x \ \exists y \ \exists z \ (Car(x) \land Car(y) \land Car(z) \land x \ne y \land x \ne z \land y \ne z).$$

Answer (score 0):

What about

$$
\exists x\exists y\exists z\, x\neq y\wedge y\neq z\wedge x\neq z \wedge \operatorname{Car}(x)\wedge \operatorname{Car}(y)\wedge \operatorname{Car}(z)
$$

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of Mauro Allegranza's answer.

Answer (score 0):

A possible (and arguably contrived) way of stating

> there are at least $n$ cars

is

> for any list of $n-1$ things (possibly with repetition), there's a car which is not in the list

Hence we get:
$$
    \forall x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}.\ \exists c.\ Car(c) \land c\neq x_1 \land \ldots \land c \neq x_{n-1}
$$

In my personal opinion, the above formula is not as readable as 
$$
  \exists c_1,\ldots,c_n.\ \bigwedge_{1\leq i\leq n}^n Car(c_i) \land 
   \bigwedge_{1\leq i<j \leq n} c_i \neq c_j
$$
which has already been proposed in other answers (modulo minor modifications).

However, the former formula requires only a *linear* amount of inequalities w.r.t. $n$, when the latter requires a *quadratic* number of such constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Just because something isn't primitive doesn't mean that it isn't logical.  You really can just write

$$\vert \{x \in \text{Garage} ~:~ x \in \text{Cars} \} \vert \ge 3$$

or even

$$\vert\text{Garage} \cap \text{Cars}\vert \ge 3$$